# Identity Server 4 where are the user claims stored

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, identityserver4

I've logged into an external provider (Google) which returned me an access token.
My external call back calls this code to get the user claims:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    // read external identity from the temporary cookie
    var info = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync(
                               IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
    var tempUser = info?.Principal;
    if (tempUser == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("External authentication error");
    }

    // retrieve claims of the external user
    var claims = tempUser.Claims.ToList();

    //Do more work
}
```

Now When I logout of Identity Server 4 and log back in, It does not make another request for consent.  Yet all of my claims are still there, where does identity server store these or are they being retrieved from the cookie some how?